# List Two Tables in Single view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Asp.net mvc4 
I have two db tables , for example student db and teachers db ,and i have to list both student table and teachers table on single page or single view

How can I send both models to a single view?

Comment: Create a view model containing properties for the collection of students and the collection of teachers

Comment: Refer the link : http://forums.asp.net/t/1700177.aspx?How+to+Display+Data+in+a+single+view+from+Multiple+Tables+in+MVC+3+0+

Answer (score 0):

You will have two models, `StudentModel,TeacherModel` , then you have to create your view model with these two models, let's say `AcadamyViewModel`.

Your Entities will be

```
public class Student
{
    ...............Properties
    ...............
}

public class Teacher
{
     ...............Properties
     ...............
}
```

Your View Model Will be

```
public class AcadamyViewModel
{
    public List<Student> StudentList{get;set;}
    public List<Teacher> TeacherList{get;set;}
}
```

Your Controller Action will be

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     var students=dbContext.Students.ToList();
     var teachers=dbContext.Teachers.ToList();
     var model=new AcadamyViewModel()
     {
           StudentList=students,
           TeacherList=teachers
     };
     return View(model);
}
```

Your View will be

```
@model MyApp.Models.AcadamyViewModel

@foreach(var item in Model.StudentList)
{
   .................
}

@foreach(var item in Model.TeacherList)
{
   ...............
}
```

This will work.